# Visual C++ not identifying gets_s

Tags: c++

So this is a simple program for practice.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

class book
{
    int bookno;
    char bookt[20];
    float price;
    float totalcost(int n)
    {
        float tot;
        tot = n * price;
        return tot;
    }
public:
    void input()
    {
        cout << "\nEnter book number: ";
        cin >> bookno;
        cout << "\nEnter book title: ";
        gets_s(bookt);                    //Does not identify this.
        cout << "\nEnter book price: ";
        cin >> price;
    }
    void purchase()
    {
        int n;
        float total;
        cout << "\nEnter the number of books to be purchase: ";
        cin >> n;
        total = totalcost(n);
        cout << "\nTotal amount is: " << total;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    book B1;
    B1.input();
    B1.purchase();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (Visual C++ 2010) does not identify `gets_s`. Identifying in the sense, it just skips the input field in output as follows:

```
OUTPUT

Enter book number: 5

Enter book title:
Enter book price: 5

Enter the number of books to be purchased: 5

Total amount is: 25
```

It just doesn't give me time to enter the book title and runs booktitle and bookprice at the same time. Help.

Comment: Why are you mixing iostreams and stdio calls? Just use an `std::string` for bookt and use `cin`.

Comment: Are you sure that maybe you are just not using it correctly? If you use it correctly you should rather write a bugreport...

Comment: I agree with Mat, mixin stdio and streams is not a good idea. The reason being that they use separate buffering. Use `std::getline` instead.

Comment: I guess it's related to the input buffer. Reading a number (bookno) leaves the newline in the buffer (since the newline is not part of the number), but functions that read whole lines are satisfied with a single '\n' in the buffer and think that the user typed an empty line.

Comment: -1: poor question title. You _think_ gets_s() has not been 'identified' but that really isn't the case. "Why does gets_s() return an empty string?" would be a much clearer statement of the issue and might have helped you work out where your problem really lay.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the new line character is not extracted from the input stream when you do:

```
cin >> bookno;
```

The quickest way for you would be to insert an extra cin.get() after it (in your input() method):

```
cout << "\nEnter book number: ";
cin >> bookno;
cin.get();
cout << "\nEnter book title: ";
gets_s(bookt);                    // Now it will identify this.
cout << "\nEnter book price: ";
cin >> price;
```

Another suggestion is try to avoid to mix C and C++ functions.